# Is this correct? 'A walk-around method'

Tags: expressions

I googled, but no related results showed up. I remembered people described that they found a bypass way to resolve a problem, but I forgot the exact expression. Thank you for any input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you mean a "[workaround](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workaround)" method.